# Write and Read keys in rEnvironment in Shiny

Tags: r, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

can someone help me with this?

Im setting up a map with maptiles by mapbox on shinyapps.io.

I saved the mapbox token in the rEnvironment. This command is not in the server-side of shiny and is run just once, when starting the script. Followed by `readRenviron("~/.Renviron")` to load all keys etc.

In the server-side before needed in leaflet I call `Sys.getenv("MAPBOX_PUBLIC_TOKEN")`

I get this error and the application shuts down
`2022-11-28T08:26:09.047038+00:00 shinyapps[7740855]:   A MAPBOX_PUBLIC_TOKEN already exists. You can overwrite it with the argument overwrite=TRUE 2022-11-28T08:26:09.047050+00:00 shinyapps[7740855]: Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous> 2022-11-28T08:26:09.047054+00:00 shinyapps[7740855]: Execution halted`

Is it the wrong way around? I tried many different ways.